# How to properly use rosbridge server and roslibjs

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to use the rosbridge server and the roslibjs. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and ros kinetic. To get it up and running I am following the tutorial from: https://msadowski.github.io/ros-web-tutorial-pt1/.

Unfortunately I ran into some problems with rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y.You can see the terminal output in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

Could it be a problem with the python version ros uses? I have python version 2.7.12 installed on my system.

Comment: Personally I would strongly recommend not using roslibjs anymore but using rosnodejs instead if you can, i.e., if your JS code is to run on the server. If not, then have you tried installing rosbridge from apt? `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server`

Comment: Thank you I will try rodnodejs instead. Yes I tried installing it with apt.